# How to create heatmaps for different rows in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, heatmap, pandas-styles

Here is the example data/script I am working with. I am trying to create two different heatmap scales from this data.

So ID1 row should have a heatmap color of red green and yellow and ID2 and ID3 should get a heatmap reverse color of red green and yellow.

I think the issue is coming from defining the C1 and C2. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = ['ID1','ID2','ID3']
cols = ['A','B','C','D']

df=pd.DataFrame(abs(np.random.randn(3, 4)), index=index, columns=cols)

c1 =  'cmap:RdYlGn'   # Heatmap for red green yellow color
c2 =  'cmap:RdYlGn_r'   # reverse heatmap for red green yellow color
d = {'ID1':c1,'ID2':c2,'ID3':c2}

df.style.apply(lambda x: x.index.map(d))
```

ID1 should get `RdYlGn` heatmap and ID2 and ID3 should get `RdYlGn_r` heatmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [background_gradient](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1.5/user_guide/style.html#Builtin-styles) and [IndexSlice](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html):

```py
styler = df.style
for idx, cmap in {"ID1": "RdYlGn", "ID2": "RdYlGn_r", "ID3": "RdYlGn_r"}.items():
    styler = styler.background_gradient(cmap=cmap, subset=pd.IndexSlice[idx, :], axis=1)
```

Then, running `styler` in a Jupyter notebook cell, you get:

[image]

Comment: Very interesting. I had no idea you could do that with the styler function. Thanks so much for providing this solution, Laurent!